# Error when attempting to use PowerPoint called from VBA from a Windows Service

Tags: powerpoint, office-interop, pywin32

I've got a web server running on Apache for Windows (which is run as a Windows Service), which uses Flask and the Python win32api library to interact with PowerPoint through the Interop library. When I run the site on the development server bundled with Flask all is well. The program opens and I can convert my presentation to video.

When I try to perform the same action from the web server running as a Service, I get a `Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation` error from the `COM` layer. I am pushing the (physical) server's resources and my RAM sits at about 80% used before PowerPoint opens, but I can both open it myself and as aforementioned run it through the development web server and it works just fine.

I am using threads, and PowerPoint is being opened in a new thread from the monolith if that matters.

P.S. I know Microsoft don't condone this application of PowerPoint, but alas they don't offer a way of converting PowerPoints to video without using PowerPoint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't running PowerPoint under the correct COM identity. I changed it using `mmc -32` and adding the Component Services plug-in, then drilling down to DCOM, finding PowerPoint Slide and editing the properties to change the user. A new bug presents itself, but this is beyond the scope of this question!

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

You may consider using any third-party components designed for the server-side execution. Also, take a look at the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk).